# Docusign signer got document that I did not think they would receive

Tags: docusignapi

I am using one server template. I have 3 documents. Doc 1 and Doc 3 need to be signed by buyer and seller. Doc 2 needs to be signed by seller and attorney. The envelope definition looks like this:

```
 {
  "compositeTemplates": [
    {
      "compositeTemplateId": "1",
      "serverTemplates": [
        {
          "sequence": "1",
          "templateId": "a0d319ef-ad34-4a2e-a375-069ce2df630c"
        }
      ],
      "inlineTemplates": [
        {
          "sequence": "2",
          "recipients": {
            "signers": [
              {
                "name": "Kathy Keaton",
                "email": "KathyKeaton1@outlook.com",
                "recipientId": "1",
                "routingOrder": "1",
                "roleName": "##Buyer1"
              },
              {
                "name": "Kathy Lori"xxx,
                "email": "kathyxxx@outlook.com",
                "recipientId": "2",
                "routingOrder": "2",
                "roleName": "##Seller1"
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ],
      "document": {
        "documentId": "1",
        "name": "Here is document one of the test.docx",
        "fileExtension": "docx",
        "documentBase64": [bytearray]
      }
    },
    {
      "compositeTemplateId": "2",
      "serverTemplates": [
        {
          "sequence": "1",
          "templateId": "a0d319ef-ad34-4a2e-a375-069ce2df630c"
        }
      ],
      "inlineTemplates": [
        {
          "sequence": "2",
          "recipients": {
            "signers": [
              {
                "name": "Kathy xxx,
                "email": "kathyxxx@outlook.com",
                "recipientId": "2",
                "routingOrder": "2",
                "roleName": "##Seller1"
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ],
      "document": {
        "documentId": "2",
        "name": "Here is document two of the test",
        "fileExtension": "docx",
        "documentBase64": [bytearray]
      }
    },
    {
      "compositeTemplateId": "3",
      "serverTemplates": [
        {
          "sequence": "1",
          "templateId": "a0d319ef-ad34-4a2e-a375-069ce2df630c"
        }
      ],
      "inlineTemplates": [
        {
          "sequence": "2",
          "recipients": {
            "signers": [
              {
                "name": "Kathy Keaton",
                "email": "KathyKeaton1@outlook.com",
                "recipientId": "1",
                "routingOrder": "1",
                "roleName": "##Buyer1"
              },
              {
                "name": "Kathy xxx",
                "email": "kathyxxx@outlook.com",
                "recipientId": "2",
                "routingOrder": "2",
                "roleName": "##Seller1"
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ],
      "document": {
        "documentId": "3",
        "name": "Here is document three of the test",
        "fileExtension": "docx",
        "documentBase64": [bytearray]
      }
    }
  ],
  "status": "sent",
  "emailSubject": "Please sign the following document at 12:47 PM"
}
```

My question is: Doc 2 went to my first signer, even though they had no signing tabs on that document. Why did that happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the document visibility feature of DocuSign. If you have doc visibility 'off', then all recipients in an envelope will have visibility to all documents in the envelope. If you have it enabled, then a recipient will need to have at least one DocuSign tab assigned to them to view the document (and all the pages this document contains). If a document has zero tabs, then it should be viewable by all.

Comment: Yes, the doc visibility is set to off on this account.

Comment: I see a total of 5 different options, including off. It says "Documents without signers are always visible".

Comment: There are some good support resources available for the various settings for document visibility: https://support.docusign.com/en/articles/How-do-I-control-which-documents-individual-signers-see-in-an-envelope-Document-Visibility